# Ionic2 - can't select/unselect ion-radio

Tags: ionic2

I updated my IONIC2 project from beta 7 to beta 10; in beta 7 the below code was working perfectly; however, after the update it stopped working.

**The expected behavior (was working on beta 7):**

When the user clicks only on a radio button, it should be checked.

**The current behavior:**

When the user clicks anywhere on the screen the radio button is checked.

I guess the issue is somehow related to this line of code, which, when I removed and tried to click anywhere on the screen, nothing is checked, which is totally normal, that's why I guess that it's a bug related to Beta 10:

```
<ion-radio checked="false" value="option1"></ion-radio>
```

Below is the non-working code (which was working on beta 7):

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>CHECKOUT</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="checkout">
    <div class="listTitle">PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OF THE BELOW OPTIONS</div>
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="content">
        <ion-item *ngIf="(option1)" class="listItems">
            <ion-label>{{option1}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio checked="false" value="option1"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

    <div class="spacing"></div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="orderNowFooter">
    <button class="orderButton" [disabled]="!content">
         <div class="centeredWhiteText">ORDER NOW</div>
    </button>
</ion-footer>
```

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.9.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `</ion-list>`. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbElJ4oEMX181L2wRYx6?p=preview) you can see a working plunker (using `ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.10`), with the same code as your question, but adding that closing `</ion-list>` tag.